# Waiting for os command to end in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, popen

In my python program i am running:

```
os.popen('sh download.sh')
```

where `download.sh` downloads a couple of csv files using curl.
Is there a way to wait until the files are downloaded before the python programm continues running?

Answer (score 0):

you can solve the problem by defining the command as a subprocess:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('sh download.sh', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

(output, err) = p.communicate()  

#This makes the wait possible
p_status = p.wait()

#This will give you the output of the command being executed
print("Command output: " + output)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use "subprocess" and process.wait() function. For example:

```
import subprocess
your_process_name = subprocess.Popen('sh','download.sh')
your_process_name.wait()
```